# Edit Delete Actions similar to UITableViewCell for UITableView sections

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I make an effect similar to `UITableView's` `'Edit'` and `'Delete'` buttons on swipe for `UITableView's` `section's header` view? I tried swipe gesture for the view but couldn't get the bouncy behaviour. Could anyone help me/direct me to right direction?

Something similar to this:
[image]

Comment: You have to create custom view and add in TableViewCell(custom TableviewCell) and then you can use swipe gesture for swipe left and right.

Comment: I need the swipe behavour in section, not cell. And I have tried the swipe gesture already for left and right but couldn't get a smooth scrolling with bouncy behavour as you otherwise can find in iOS native cell's swipe action.

Comment: Consider to use a plain tableview instead of a grouped one. Then you can design cells that look like section headers and use them to separate the other cells. Indexing will be a bit difficult but not as challenging as to mimic cell behaviour.